# SublimeLinter(ST3/ST2) for C++ (cppcheck/cppint.py)

Tags: c++, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

Equip: Ubuntu 13.04, Sublime 3 + SublimeLinter(was installed from git).

Also, was installed package cppcheck. (aptitude install cppcheck).

cpplint.py was downloaded from google.

Trouble: Sublime doesn`t emphasize errors C++. (python is OK).

What have done, my setting - user:

```
{
  "sublimelinter_syntax_map":
  {
     "Python Django": "python",
     "C++": "c_cpplint" //*doesn`t work.
     // "C++": "/usr/bin/cppheck" *doesn`t work.

  },
  "sublimelinter_executable_map":
  {
     "c_cpplint": "/home/name/scripts/cpplint.py",  // *doesn`t work
     // "c_cpplint":"/usr/bin/cppheck" * doesn`t work    
     "python": "usr/bin/python"

  }
}
```

What`s the deal?

ST2:

cppcheck do nothing.

via cpplint.py

[picture](http://i60.fastpic.ru/big/2013/1208/dc/33352cc96887d2fd9cfed5db564708dc.png)

Many thanks.

Comment: SublimeLinter is not supported on Sublime 3. [SublimeLinter3](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3) is in process, but not ready for use yet, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, I`ve installed ST2.
But, cppcheck doesn`t work at all, and
cpplint.py works uncorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/449)'s the solution I've read for cpplint, works perfectly for me. I did the

```
sudo pip install cpplint
```

instead of downloading the .py and put it somewhere. This seems to do the trick.

Some people say it's the permission issue on cpplint.py. Try chmod 755 might be another solution(I've not tried it though)